# how can I get the date from String using regex in java?

Tags: java, regex

here's my code:

```
String t1="postby <span title=\"2011-4-5 17:22\">yesterday&nbsp;17:22</span>";
String t2="postby 2010-11-12 10:02";
```

I want get `2011-4-5 17:22` , `2010-11-12 10:02` from `t1` or `t2`,using one regex expression

(input `t1` or `t2`,output the date)

how to do? (please give to me some example code,thanks)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \d{2}:\d{2}
```

A few notes:

- you will have to escape the slashes in a string: `String pattern = "\\d{4}-\\d{1,2}....."`
- `\d` means "digit" (0-9)
- `{x}` means "x times"
- `{x,y}` means "at least x, but not more than y times"

Reference: [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: Excellent. To make it even safer, one could add \b at the beginning and the end.

Answer (score 1):

How many false matches will you allow? Bozho [already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565582/how-can-i-get-the-date-from-stirng-using-regex-in-java/5565621#5565621) the pattern

```
\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \d{2}:\d{2}
```

But that matches the following questionable cases: `0000-1-1 00:00` (there is no year zero), `2011-0-1 00:00` (there is no month zero), `2011-13-1 00:00` (there is no month 13), `2011-1-32 00:00` (there is no month-day 32) `2011-12-31 24:00` (there is at most one leap second) and `2011-12-31 23:61` (there is at most one leap seond).

You are wanting to parse date-times that are *almost*, but not quite, in [ISO-8601 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). If you can, **please** use that international standard format.

In one of my programs (a shell script using `grep`), I've used the following regular expression:

```
^20[0-9][0-9]-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]T[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]UTC$
```

I had an extra `T` and `UTC` to deal with, was interested only in dates in this century, and parsed with seconds precision. I see I was not so restrictive on hour and minute values, probably because traditional C/C++ conversions can handle them.

I guess you therefore could use something like the following:

```
\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\d [0-2]\d:[0-6]\d
```